# Exercise from Rotman, Advanced modern algebra , $\wedge^2 (\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p) \neq 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

(i) Let $p$ be a prime,. Show that $\wedge^2 (\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p) \neq 0$ , where  $\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p$ si viewed as $\mathbb{Z}$-module (  with $\mathbb{Z}_p $ I mean $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ )

(ii) Let $D = \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ . Prove that $\wedge^2 D = 0$

What I have done: for the point (ii) $$D \otimes D = (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \otimes (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^{4} (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) $$ but $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is divisible, and so $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} = 0$ .

Thus $\wedge^2 D = 0$ because $\wedge^2 D$ is a submodule of $D \otimes D$ .

I'm stuck on point (i) , I should find a bilinear alternating map defined on $ (\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p) \times (\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p) $ which is not $0$ , but which one ?

Comment: What is $\mathbb Z_p$? It would probably be good to be explicit about Rotman's definition of $\wedge$, too...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: is $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Add that information to the question itself.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: It may be helpful to write $((a,b),(c,d))\in(\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}_p \oplus \mathbb{Z}_p)$ as a $2\times 2$ matrix in $\Bbb Z_p$. Can you think of any maps that are bilinear and alternating on the columns (or rows) of a matrix?

Comment: yes of course I can :D